# QGIS GDAL selects XYZ driver rather than GTIFF etc

Tags: qgis, gdal, mac

I think this is an issue to do with running QGIS on a mac but I might be wrong.
When I run a GDAL tool like clipper or translate GDAL seems to select the -XYZ driver regardless of what the input files are so the tool fails to run properly. If I manually edit the GDAL script to change the -XYZ to GTIFF the tool runs fine. 
I have been living with this for a while but it would be nice to fix it.

QGIS 2.18 kyngKhaos MAC OSX 1405.7461 El Capitan i7 32GB ram

Comment: Please, add an exemple of your datasource and part of script you are running.

Comment: I can confirm it's an issue as I have the same problem on a very similar Mac, although it doesn't pick XYZ but something else - best log it as a bug (I've been meaning to for ages): https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: I noticed something similar happening in QGIS 2.18.3 (Ubuntu), although in my case it defaulted to AiiGrid(?) Happened a few days ago, but not been able to reproduce this since. Can you list the exact steps you took, plus the original raster type and file name? And did your original raster file have a correct file extension, as the code looks this up to guess which driver to default to?

Comment: For those who want specifics .... gdal_translate -of XYZ "/Volumes/GIS/10k base.tif" /Users/Desktop/10kbase.tif